# re.search with strings: difference between use cases of re.rearch() with strings

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import re
l=['fang', 'yi', 'ke', 'da', 'xue', 'xue', 'bao', '=', 'journal', 'of', 'southern', 'medical', 'university', '2015/feb']
t=[l[13]]
t2=['2015/Feb']

wl1=['2015/Feb']

for i in t:
    print(type(i))
    print(type(wl1[0]))
    r=re.search(r'^%s$' %i, wl1[0])
    if r:
        print('yes')

for i in t2:
    print(type(i))
    print(type(wl1[0]))
    r2=re.search(r'^%s$' %i, wl1[0])
    if r2:
        print('yes')
```

Could anyone explain me why in the first loop it does not match the two strings? In the second it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your input value is **lowercase**:

```
>>> l=['fang', 'yi', 'ke', 'da', 'xue', 'xue', 'bao', '=', 'journal', 'of', 'southern', 'medical', 'university', '2015/feb']
>>> t=[l[13]]
>>> t[0]
'2015/feb'
```

while you are trying to match against a value with the `F` uppercased:

```
>>> wl1=['2015/Feb']
>>> wl1[0]
'2015/Feb'
```

As such the regular expression `^2015/feb$` won't match, while in your second example you generated the expression `^2015/Feb$` instead.

Comment: Right, sorry about that